# I'm trying to make a greedy Regex to extract numbers from Strings, considering thousands and decimal places

Tags: .net, regex

I need a Regex for numbers that considers thousands and decimal places. The one I came up so far is:

```
\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*(,\d*)?
```

It will catch `3.000,00` as well as `3,00` and `3.000`. Sweet.

The problem is that I need it to be very greedy, and capture larger numbers first, for instance, for this input:

```
125,45.124.890,45,32,67.456
```

I'd need it to capture `45.124.890,45` as a number. It's important to me because it's the biggest one. My regex just won't work, because it will capture `123,45` and then `45` will not be considered for the next match. So the next number it captures is `124.890,45` which is not good for me.

Any thoughts?

**PS** As I'm brazillian the separators are inverted

Comment: is this the data `125|45,124,890.45|32|67,456` ? Can you separate the number with a different character?

Comment: this is input is not under my control :(

Comment: so a , here can represent both the end of number or a decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?!0\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+(?![\d\.]))?
```

#### C# demo:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    const string line = @"125,45.124.890,45,32,67.456";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(line, 
      @"(?!0\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d+(?![\d\.]))?");
    foreach(Match match in matches)
    {
      foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output:

```
125
45.124.890,45
32
67.456
```

Test this demo **[here](http://ideone.com/VzrKM)**.